# How to find the number of solutions to an equation in wolfram alpha

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

Given the equation: $$sin(x)=\frac{x}{218}$$How do I use Wolfram Alpha to find the number of positive solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, with varying degrees of reliance on Wolfram Alpha vs manual analysis. A simple (and pretty mindless) approach is to run WA queries such as

```
sin(x)=x/218, 20<x<50
```

which should tell you that there are 9 solutions in this range. A few queries like this will cover the range $0 \leq x \leq 218$, and you then need only observe that the equation can have no solutions greater than $218$ (why?) and that every positive solution is mirrored by a negative one.